# Differential and partial derivates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can you help with the following question?

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with continuous derivatives.
It is given that $f\left(\dfrac{\cos(t)}{t},\dfrac{\sin(t)}{t}\right)$ is growing for $t > 0$.

Proof that $Df(0,0)=(0,0)$.   (The differential of $f$ in the point $(0,0)$ is $(0,0)$).

Thanks!